# "Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided" in Visual Studio 2015 Load Testing

Tags: visual-studio

Whenever I was trying to capture a scenario, I kept getting this error message:

> Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided.

I will answer my own question so that people can benefit from my findings.I googled for an hour but with no luck. So I decided to debug this issue on my own, and used ProcMon.exe from SysInternals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, after using ProcMon.exe to find out, was really a missing entry in the Registry. Visual Studio 2015 was looking at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE` this entry to look up where Internet Explorer is located. But for some reason, this entry was missing in my registry. Since it could not find the location of IE, it failed at opening the IE to capture a web testing scenario. The message really tells us that fact.

This is how it should look like after you added the registry entry, but you don't have to have `Path` key. The `(Default)` is enough.:

[image]

Comment: Similar situation with TGit extension when TortoiseGit installation didn't include 32-bit shell extensions (it was looking at WOW3264 node in the registry which was absent).